# Redirect domain to localhost works in Edge, does not work in Chrome

Tags: windows, apache, laravel, xampp, localhost

This is my host file in /etc/driver

```
127.0.0.1 myhost.eu
127.0.0.1 *.myhost.eu
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost eparafie.eu> 
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\myhost\public"
    ServerName myhost.eu
    ServerAlias myhost.eu
    <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\myhost\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *.myhost.eu> 
    DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\myhost\public"
        ServerName myhost.eu
        ServerAlias myhost.eu
        <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\myhost\public">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
       </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

In EDGE - it's opening my Laravel public folder as it should do,
but in Chrome, it still going to real domain (I have it).

What is wrong?
What should I correct?

*.myhost is for that I will handle wildcard URL within my app.